# yum install mcrypt error

Tags: php, centos6

when i try to install php-mcrypt on centOs6 :

```
yum install php56w-mcrypt.x86_64
```

i got this error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php56w-mcrypt-5.6.36-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
Requires: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

then i try to install libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) but i can not find it on yum .

```
[root@host /]# yum install libmcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.hostduplex.com
 * elrepo-kernel: repos.lax-noc.com
 * extras: mirror.san.fastserv.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: mirror.hmc.edu
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
No package libmcrypt available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

this is my yum installed :

```
[root@host /]# yum list installed | grep php
php56-php-common.x86_64
php56-php-mbstring.x86_64
php56-php-mysqlnd.x86_64
php56-php-pdo.x86_64  5.6.36-1.el6.remi @remi-safe
php56-php-pecl-dom-varimport.x86_64
php56-php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64
php56-php-pecl-zip.x86_64
php56-php-xml.x86_64  5.6.36-1.el6.remi @remi-safe
php56-runtime.x86_64  2.3-1.el6.remi    @remi-safe
php56w.x86_64         5.6.36-1.w6       @webtatic
php56w-cli.x86_64     5.6.36-1.w6       @webtatic
php56w-common.x86_64  5.6.36-1.w6       @webtatic
php56w-mbstring.x86_64
php56w-mysqlnd.x86_64 5.6.36-1.w6       @webtatic
php56w-opcache.x86_64 5.6.36-1.w6       @webtatic
php56w-pdo.x86_64     5.6.36-1.w6       @webtatic
```

i still do not know what's diff between php56 and php56w.
should i remove all php5.6 and install a new one?

Comment: Don't mix "remi" and "webtatic. For "remi" follow the wizard: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/ and libmxrypt is in EPEL.

Comment: About mcrypt, please read: https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt